# How to unpack a map/list in scala to tuples for a variadic function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a PairRDD in spark. For that I need a tuple2 RDD, like `RDD[(String, String)]`. However, I have an `RDD[Map[String, String]]`.

I can't work out how to get rid of the iterable so I'm just left with `RDD[(String, String)]` rather than e.g. `RDD[List[(String, String)]]`.

A simple demo of what I'm trying to make work is this broken code:

```
val lines = sparkContext.textFile("data.txt")
val pairs = lines.map(s => Map(s -> 1))
val counts = pairs.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

The last line doesn't work because `pairs` is an `RDD[Map[String, Int]]` when it needs to be an `RDD[(String, Int)]`.

So how can I get rid of the iterable in `pairs` above to convert the Map to just a tuple2?

Comment: As already written in my answer: Why do you create a new `Map` for each single word. This does not seem to be intended. Please read my (revised incl proof) answer carefully. Use `s => (s,1)` instead of `Map( s-> 1) `. If my answer does not match your requirements, then please reformulate your question conicisely. Thx!

Comment: This is sample code that illustrates the issue instead of including my complicated code. Obviously if there was no Map there would be no issue and no question. The issue on line 3 is fixed by the accepted answer. Yours avoids the issue by changing the sample code which doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just run:

```
val counts = pairs.flatMap(identity).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Note that the usage of the identity function that replicates the functionality of `flatten` on an RDD and the `reduceByKey()` function has a nifty underscore notation for conciseness.

Comment: Ya, your proposal also fixes the problem. But my fix in removing the "unncessary" and most probably unwanted `Map(...)` creation seems to be a much easier solution ....